# Extract array information and make a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having an array of objects. Each object has the keys: userId: String, name: String,  xp: Number. 
From this, I want to extract the name and the xp and make a list. Like:

If this would be the array:

```
[
 {
    _id: 6094d5746870c34a90d58d1b,
    userId: 'iduser1',
    name: 'User321',
    xp: 10,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 6094d29ef94abe3ee4f144dc,
    userId: 'iduser',
    name: 'User123',
    xp: 5,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I want the result to be something like:

```
User321: 10
User123: 5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map to an array of `[key, value]` entries, and transform to an object using `Object.fromEntrires()`:

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"6094d5746870c34a90d58d1b","userId":"iduser1","name":"User321","xp":10,"__v":0},{"_id":"6094d29ef94abe3ee4f144dc","userId":"iduser","name":"User123","xp":5,"__v":0}]

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map(({ name, xp }) => [name, xp])
)

console.log(result)
```

If you want a string, map each item to a string, and then join the array of strings:

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"6094d5746870c34a90d58d1b","userId":"iduser1","name":"User321","xp":10,"__v":0},{"_id":"6094d29ef94abe3ee4f144dc","userId":"iduser","name":"User123","xp":5,"__v":0}]

const result = arr
  .map(({ name, xp }) => `${name}: ${xp}`)
  .join('\n')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've added another answer that generates a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const arr = [
 {
    _id: '6094d5746870c34a90d58d1b',
    userId: 'iduser1',
    name: 'User321',
    xp: 10,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '6094d29ef94abe3ee4f144dc',
    userId: 'iduser',
    name: 'User123',
    xp: 5,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(`${curr.name}: ${curr.xp}`);
    return acc;
}, []).join('\r\n');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want result in an object**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    _id: "6094d5746870c34a90d58d1b",
    userId: "iduser1",
    name: "User321",
    xp: 10,
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "6094d29ef94abe3ee4f144dc",
    userId: "iduser",
    name: "User123",
    xp: 5,
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name, xp } = curr;
  acc[name] = xp;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**If you want result in an array of objects**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    _id: "6094d5746870c34a90d58d1b",
    userId: "iduser1",
    name: "User321",
    xp: 10,
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "6094d29ef94abe3ee4f144dc",
    userId: "iduser",
    name: "User123",
    xp: 5,
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const result = arr.map((o) => ({ [o.name]: o.xp }));

console.log(result);
```